# Asking for help through Google Hangouts

Tags: support, asking-questions, chat

[Google Hangouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Hangouts) is a great tool. You can screen share, discuss live, even remote control if given permission. Not to mention lots of other tools.

In my studies, I've used it to help others with programs and receive help with great success.

What is Stack Overflow's opinion on the matter? Is it OK to ask if someone has spare time to help through hangout after posting an initial question? Then once a solution is determined post the results.

Thoughts?

Comment: The policy here is - don't bother users. If they leave a contact info in their profile you can contact them. If not - don't ask.

Comment: It's one my my pet peeves at another forum where I hang out -- after unwillingly being promoted to "Top User", I started to get PMs asking/inquiring/demanding "personal assistance". Initially, I politely replied I don't do that, nowadays I delete them. Un-read.

Comment: It would be on a per question basis if one so chooses. Not a PM whoever you can to try and get a response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow has a chat system that's intended for, basically, this purpose, to the extent SE/SO approves of it at all (which is limited).  If your question is one of the major languages, there is probably a chatroom where you can ask your question.

In terms of actually having a detailed hangout session, no, SE/SO isn't intended for that purpose.  You can use [Google Helpouts](https://helpouts.google.com/) if you want that sort of help.

Comment: Well said, was not aware of google helpouts. Thank you. I would like to leave saying given what you just mentioned, ultimately it would be in the benefit of the site's ability to help people to not restrict their helping tools. IMO. Also google helpout seems to be a scheduled event, whereas here it would be more on the spot and entirely free. Plus their aid is restricted.

Comment: @Nonlin providing one-on-one help is not really Stack Overflow's primary mission. It is building an archive of knowledge - to which hangouts and other transient methods don't really contribute.

Comment: That can still be achieved via hangouts, you just document the answer on the post. The only reason why I see it not working is if people just don't want it and I guess the truth is, not enough people do.

Comment: @Nonlin I doubt very much how many users would actually bother documenting the results of a hangout troubleshooting session, in a manner that is useful (and applicable) to someone else.  Have you ever done that yourself? Most people have trouble documenting  the minutes of a meeting they've been in at work, and they get *paid* for that.

Comment: @Pekka Well no, but I assume it would just be writing down the solution once its found. Regardless this site just isn't the place for this kind of thing. Maybe it will be, but it seems like its to soon to even mention it judging by the amount of down votes its receiving.